# Flowable with Docker does not startup - Tomcat HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Tags: docker, tomcat, catalina, flowable

I'm trying to get up and running a flowable instance but it's not working. Docker is running and I've deleted all images and processes. All I did was run

```
docker run -p8080:8080 flowable/all-in-one
```

I've tried going to `http://localhost:8080/flowable-admin` but this is what I have:

[image]

In my terminal I have all [these exceptions](https://codeshare.io/axj1kX) (too long to write them here), but then the server has start up

```
    08-Apr-2019 07:54:53.340 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/opt/tomcat/webapps/flowable-task.war] has finished in [74,627] ms
08-Apr-2019 07:54:53.342 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT]
08-Apr-2019 07:54:53.388 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [47] ms
08-Apr-2019 07:54:53.389 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/docs]
08-Apr-2019 07:54:53.399 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/docs] has finished in [9] ms
08-Apr-2019 07:54:53.399 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/examples]
08-Apr-2019 07:54:53.535 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/examples] has finished in [136] ms
08-Apr-2019 07:54:53.535 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/host-manager]
08-Apr-2019 07:54:53.556 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/host-manager] has finished in [21] ms
08-Apr-2019 07:54:53.556 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/manager]
08-Apr-2019 07:54:53.581 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/manager] has finished in [24] ms
08-Apr-2019 07:54:53.593 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
08-Apr-2019 07:54:53.607 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
08-Apr-2019 07:54:53.610 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 296018 ms
```

What can I do?

Comment: From the [README](https://github.com/flowable/flowable-engine/tree/master/docker/all-in-one) it seems that you are using a url that doesn't exist. Try the following: Flowable IDM http://localhost:8080/flowable-idm, Flowable Modeler http://localhost:8080/flowable-modeler, Flowable Task http://localhost:8080/flowable-task, Flowable Admin http://localhost:8080/flowable-admin

Comment: They do not work either, still giving the same error (404 not found tomcat)

Comment: I can't recreate the problem. For me, it worked without any issues after running `docker run -p 8080:8080 flowable/all-in-one`.

Comment: Looking at the exceptions it seems like they are all trying to create the same database instance. Have you modified the image perhaps? It is weird why it isn't working for one person, but working for another one